# CDI 1.X asynchronous events

Tags: java, cdi

I was looking at this project https://github.com/MSzturc/cdi-async-events-extension/,
which provides async events in CDI 1.X (built-in async came from 2.0).

Now I'm questioning this piece of code inside the custom `Extension`:

```
public <X> void processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<X> event, final BeanManager beanManager) {
    final AnnotatedType<X> type = event.getAnnotatedType();
    for (AnnotatedMethod<?> method : type.getMethods()) {
        for (final AnnotatedParameter<?> param : method.getParameters()) {
            if (param.isAnnotationPresent(Observes.class) && param.isAnnotationPresent(Async.class)) {
                asyncObservers.add(ObserverMethodHolder.create(this.pool, beanManager, type, method, param));
            }
        }
    }
}

public void afterBeanDiscovery(@Observes AfterBeanDiscovery event) {
    for (ObserverMethod<?> om : this.asyncObservers) {
        event.addObserverMethod(om);
    }
}
```

Basically, while each Bean is being registered, it is looking at each method to see if a parameter has the `@Async` annotation.

Then, after the discovery step, it is registering the `@Observes @Async` methods.
Looking inside the `addObserverMethod()` method, provided by JBoss Weld 2, I see:

```
additionalObservers.add(observerMethod);
```

My question then is, wouldn't those methods be called twice? I mean, they may be registered twice, first by the container itself, then by calling the `addObserverMethod()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with project, but from the first look it seems *pretty outdated and not maintained.*

As for the extension - it basically adds the "same" observer method (OM) again, with it's own OM implementation. So I would say the behaviour depends on CDI implementation as the spec does not guarantee what happens when you register "the same" OM again - is it replaced or is it just added like you say?

And by "the same" I mean the exact same underlying Java method although wrapped in a fancier coat.

Ultimately, you can easily try it and see for yourself, but I would advise against using that project as any problems you bump into are unlikely to be resolved on the project side.

Comment: You're right, I think I'll stick to managing threads externally for the moment. Thanks for your time!